# Position relative - why does setting the "left" property move the box to the right

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am practicing positioning , to be more specific position relative. The example I am studying is about creating 3 boxes , each different color and practice move them to understand positioning.

```css
.boxes {
  border: 3px solid lightgreen
}

.box {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.box-one {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.box-two {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  position: relative;
  left: 5rem;
}

.box-three {
  background-color: rgb(213, 142, 213);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box box-one"></div>
  <div class="box box-two"></div>
  <div class="box box-three"></div>
```

Let's focus on the box box-two which is the only one with positioning , the result is this box will be moved to the right
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmpYn.jpg)

The question is : Why if the instruction is : left 5rem , it moves the box to the opposite position ( right ) and if I set it to right : 5rem , then it moves it to the left? why is it backwards.

Comment: `left: 5rem` means move box from left origin up to 5rem. Hence Box is moved towards right. i.e. `left, right, top, bottom` means the distance from origin to mentioned direction.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the way you are reading it. Let's look at the CSS in question:

```css
.box-two {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  position: relative;
  left: 5rem;
}
```

Right now, you are reading the CSS as *"move the box to the left `5rem`"*, which is the source of your confusion because the box appears to move to the right.

However, the CSS `left` property isn't telling the box to move to the right. Instead, it's telling the left edge of box to move `5rem` from where it normally would be. This results in the box appearing to move to the right.